# Doctrine query builder - Too few parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I made a Doctrine query builder query and I have this error :

```
Too few parameters : The query defines 3 parameters but you only bound 2.
```

I have looked at the query and tried some refactoring but I can't find where the code is wrong.

The query :

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('m')
      ->from(Matiere::class, 'm')
      ->join('m.ues', 'ue')
      ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('ue.semester', ':semestre'))
      ->setParameter('semestre', $semestre);

if (count($UEs) === 1) {
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->neq('ue.id', ':ueSpe'))
          ->setParameter('ueSpe', $UEs);
}
else {
    $ueM = $UEs[0];
    $ueP = $UEs[1];
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->neq('ue.id', ':ueM'))
          ->andWhere($query->expr()->neq('ue.id', ':ueP'))
          ->setParameters(['ueM' => $ueM, 'ueP' => $ueP]);
}
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('m')
      ->from(Matiere::class, 'm')
      ->join('m.ues', 'ue')
      ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('ue.semester', ':semestre'))
      ->setParameter('semestre', $semestre);

if (count($UEs) === 1) {
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->neq('ue.id', ':ueSpe'))
          ->setParameter('ueSpe', $UEs);
}
else {
    $parameters[] = $UEs[0];
    $parameters[] = $UEs[1];
    $query->andWhere($qb->expr()->notIn('ue.id', ':parameters'))
          ->setParameter('parameters' => $parameters);
}
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

`setParameters()` overrides any previous `setParameter()` call. So, you have to individually set properties using setParameter, or make sure they dont overlap by using an `if` condition.

Comment: This looks more like a Comment, since it doesn't include the exact code necessary to solve the OP's issue. See StackOverflow.com/help for more info. Your explanation is *great*, and it's always recommended to include an explanation like this in your Answers. Upvotes are generally accrued over time for quality answers as future visitors learn something to help with their own code bases. Consider `editing` to also embed an example coded solution.

Comment: This comment really helped me. If you use ->addCriteria to add a previously defined criteria to your querybuilder, and then set setParameters after that, you will also have this problem, if there are any parameters in your Criteria (if you use expression language, it has).